# How to create table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Technically, I created one but the result is not satisfied for me because I want if index !== 0 to put date under the row to look it more readable for users. But now when I have more then one they all stand in one line.

```
                  .map((p, index) => (
                          <tr key={p.id}>
                              <td> {p.name}</td>
                              {Object.entries(p.cena)
                                .filter(([key]) => checkKw(correctSize, key))
                                .map(([key, value], index) => {
                               if(index === 0){
                                  return (
                                    <>   
                                   
                                        <td>                               
{key }</td>
                                        <td>
                                          {" "}
                                          {(value * 1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          {cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                            value * 1.1,
                                            wysokoscDotacji,
                                            stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                                          ).toFixed(1)}
                                        </td>
                                    </>
                                  );
                                }  else {   return (         <>   
                                   
                                  <td>                               
{key }</td>
                                  <td>
                                    {" "}
                                    {(value * 1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    {cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                      value * 1.1,
                                      wysokoscDotacji,
                                      stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                                    ).toFixed(1)}
                                  </td>
                              </>
                                                                          
                                                                          )    

                                }
                                
                               } )}
                          </tr>*
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
```

update:
I try to use another approach

```
var reactElementUl = React.createElement(
                                  'tr', {
                                      className: 'myList'
                                  },
                                      React.createElement('td', {id: 'li1'}, key),
                                      React.createElement('td', {id: 'li2'}, (value * 1.1).toFixed(1)),
                                      React.createElement('td', {id: 'li3'}, cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                        value * 1.1,
                                        wysokoscDotacji,
                                        stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                                      ).toFixed(1))
                              );
```

it work if I returned it. But I want it move to *
how do it without useEffect classNames appendChild etc?

Comment: Did you try my latest solution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a new `<tr>` for each row.

Add an `</tr>` to end the row, add a new `<tr>` to start a new row when `index !== 0`:

```
.map((p, index) => (
    Object.entries(p.cena)
        .filter(([key]) => checkKw(correctSize, key))
        .map(([key, value], index) => {
            if(index === 0) {
                return (
                    <>              
                        <tr key={p.id}>
                            <td> {p.name}</td> 
                            <td>{key }</td>
                            <td>
                                {" "}
                                {(value * 1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                value * 1.1,
                                wysokoscDotacji,
                                stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                                ).toFixed(1)}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </>
                )
            }  else {
                return (
                <>          
                    <tr key={p.id}>
                        <td> {p.name}</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{key}</td>
                        <td>
                            {" "}
                            {(value * 1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                value * 1.1,
                                wysokoscDotacji,
                                stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                                ).toFixed(1)}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </>
                )
            }
    })};
)
```

---

Alternatively, if that logic above doesn't work, you can just use CSS to force the table to *look* like it's using another row, by using flex styles. You'll probably want to move these inline styles into a CSS file:

```
.map((p, index) => (
    <tr key={p.id} style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100%;">
        {Object.entries(p.cena)
            .filter(([key]) => checkKw(correctSize, key))
            .map(([key, value], index) => {
                if (index === 0) {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <td style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 25%"> {p.name}</td>
                            <td style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 25%">{key}</td>
                            <td style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 25%">
                                {" "}
                                {(value * 1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto
                            </td>
                            <td style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 25%">
                                {cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                    value * 1.1,
                                    wysokoscDotacji,
                                    stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                                ).toFixed(1)}
                            </td>
                        </>
                    );
                } else {
                    return (<>
                        <td style="flex-basis: 100%"> {p.name}</td>                     
                        <td style="flex-basis: 25%">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex-basis: 25%">{key}</td>
                        <td style="flex-basis: 25%">
                            {" "}
                            {(value * 1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex-basis: 25%">
                            {cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(
                                value * 1.1,
                                wysokoscDotacji,
                                stawkaPodatkuDochodowego
                            ).toFixed(1)}
                        </td>
                    </>

                    )

                }

            })}
    </tr>
  ))}
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, you'll have to provide more details, because it's not easy to understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you good understand what I want but the problem is that I cannot use ``` </tr> ``` after React.Fragment.

Comment: I've edited my answer, but I'm flying blind not knowing what you're mapping originally. Have you tried to separate out the entire row logic like this?

Comment: Added an alternative approach using CSS to force the table to look like the data is in a new row. Move that `<td>` with the `&nbsp;` wherever you want the empty cell to go